# UIActivityViewController - sharing text, url, image shown differently on iOS 10

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, imessage

When I share [image, url, text] as the activity items, in iOS 9 it appears as 3 separate items in the text message.  In iOS 10, sharing a link from Safari shows an image with the website name.  How is this done?

**Here is Code,**

```
NSArray *items = @[datTextString,url,image ]; 
UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```

[image: iOS 10]

[image: iOS 9]

Comment: Please add the code for UIActivityViewController that you have tried.

Comment: NSArray *items = @[datTextString,url,image ];
            UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of iOS 10 to display the thumbnail view of the URL.

Comment: In my App, I am providing the image, text, and url.  Is it possible to wrap the URL in the image?